# Service time measurement

Tags: android, time, service, metrics, android-mediasession

I have a service, that uses `MediaSession` for playing streams. I want to collect the time, how much this service plays music and then send it to the server. I use following code (simplified):

```
public class MyService extends MediaBrowserServiceCompat {

  private Long startTime;

  public class MediaPlayerListener extends PlaybackInfoListener {

    @Override
    public void onPlaybackStateChange(PlaybackStateCompat state) {
       session.setPlaybackState(state);

       switch (state.getState()) {
           case PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING:
               startTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
               startForeground(MediaNotificationManager.NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
               break;
           case PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_STOPPED:
               long timediff = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - startTime;
               stopForeground(true);
               stopSelf();
               // timediff is being sent to the server here 
               break;
       }
   }
}
```

The service works as expected, but time reporting not. On server, some of the listening times are OK, but some of them are really big, more than 200 hours. As this service is used to listen to streams, it is not possible or realistic to calculate such value. I am therefore convinced that this reporting is not good. I also tried to replace `SystemClock` with `System#currentTimeMillis`, but the values are very big as well. Could somebody tell me, how to measure listening time correctly or provide me some best practices?

Comment: Have you tried to store the playback start time and stop time in local storage such as shared preferences or a database? I think the problem is that the start time of your implementation has been reset.

Comment: How it can be reset? What might be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Try sending time difference to server before calling stopSelf().
Sometimes it may not have enough time to send it. stopSelf() stops service as soon as possible. Another service to handle sending timedifference?

Comment: No, I do not send it to server there. I just save it to database and send it later. I just pasted it there to make the code more readable for you. Moreover, this would not alter the values.